# Kubernetes pod cluster ip not responding?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two backend services deployed on the `Google cloud Kubernetes Engine`.

a) Backend Service

b) Admin portal which needed to connect with the Backend Service

Everything is available in one cluster.

As in `Workload / Pods`,

I have three deployments running whereas `fitme:9000` is a backend and `nginx-1:9000` is an admin portal service
[image]

whereas in `Services` I have 
[image]

## Visualization

[image]

## Explanation

```
1. D1 (fitme), D2 (mongo-mongodb), D3 (nginx-1) are three deployments

2. E1D1 (fitme-service), E2D1 (fitme-jr29g), E1D2 (mongo-mongodb), E2D2 (mongo-mongodb-rcwwc) and E1D3 (nginx-1-service) are Services

3. `E1D1, E1D2 and E1D3` are exposed over `Load Balancer` whereas `E2D1 , E2D2` are exposed over `Cluster IP`.
```

The reason behind it:

`D1` needs to access `D2` (internally) -> This is perfectly working fine. I am using `E2D2` exposed service (cluster IP) to access the `D2` deployment inside from `D1`

Now,  `D3` needs access to `D1` deployment. So, I exposed `D1` as an `E2D1` service and trying to access it internally by generated `Cluster IP` of `E2D1` but it's giving me `request time out`.

## YAML for `fitme-jr29g` service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-02T11:18:55Z"
  generateName: fitme-
  labels:
    app: fitme
  name: fitme-jr29g
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "486673"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/fitme-8t7rl
  uid: 875045eb-14f5-11ea-823c-42010a8e0047
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.35.240.95
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: fitme
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

## YAML for `nginx-1-service` service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-02T11:30:10Z"
  labels:
    app: admin
  name: nginx-1-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "489972"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/admin-service
  uid: 195b462e-14f7-11ea-823c-42010a8e0047
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.35.250.90
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30628
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: admin
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.227.26.101
```

## YAML for nginx-1 deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-02T11:24:09Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: admin
  name: admin
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "489624"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/admin
  uid: 426792e6-14f6-11ea-823c-42010a8e0047
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: admin
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: admin
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/docker-226818/admin@sha256:602fe6b7e43d53251eebe2f29968bebbd756336c809cb1cd43787027537a5c8b
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: admin-sha256
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-12-02T11:24:18Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-12-02T11:24:18Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-12-02T11:24:09Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-12-02T11:24:18Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "admin-8d55dfbb6" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 2
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

## YAML for `fitme-service`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-02T13:38:21Z"
  generateName: fitme-
  labels:
    app: fitme
  name: fitme-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "525173"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/drogo-mzcgr
  uid: 01e8fc39-1509-11ea-823c-42010a8e0047
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.35.240.74
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31016
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: fitme
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.236.110.230
```

## YAML for fitme deployment

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-02T13:34:54Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: fitme
  name: fitme
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "525571"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/drogo
  uid: 865a5a8a-1508-11ea-823c-42010a8e0047
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drogo
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: fitme
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/fitme-226818/drogo@sha256:ab49a4b12e7a14f9428a5720bbfd1808eb9667855cb874e973c386a4e9b59d40
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: fitme-sha256
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-12-02T13:34:57Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-12-02T13:34:57Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-12-02T13:34:54Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-12-02T13:34:57Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "drogo-5c7f449668" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 2
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

I am accessing `fitme-jr29g` by putting  `10.35.240.95:9000` ip address in
`nginx-1 deployment` container.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then `nginx-1-service` is "connecting" to another service `fitme-jr29g`. How is it trying to connect? Is `nginx-1-service` exposing it or are you fetching it from one of the pods in the `nginx-1` deployment? Maybe if you share your YAML definitions for deployments and services.

Comment: Yes, `nginx-1-service` is internally calling `fitme-jr29g`.  I exposed `fitme-jr29g` on cluster IP and using the same IP in `nginx-1-service` internally.

Comment: Using the same IP internally? You mean, 2 services with the same address? Can you please share your YAML definitions for better understanding?

Comment: @yyyyahir Yes, sharing

Comment: @yyyyahir Please checkout the Edit section

Comment: @yyyyahir I have added an Image and improve the explanation

Comment: So, is not shared but I assume that since the *fitme* service is targeting port 9000, that is also open in the deployed pods, right? Maybe also include that YAML?

Comment: @yyyyahir added

Comment: OK so, `services` are meant to act as some sort of internal load balancer and forward requests to pods. Pods are grouped into `deployments` and can be ready to receive incoming requests, if configured correctly. You just shared another service, which is not expecting **any** requests from the *fitme* service. You need to share the deployment that is being exposed by said service. It might be **not** listening on port 9000. We want to make sure of that.

Comment: ok sharing but as I said the deployment is working perfectly if I access through the load balancer (static IP on 9000 port ). I am accessing fitme deployment through <staticIpAddress>:80 and using port mapping 80:9000.

Comment: @yyyyahir shared but I don't get it. port mapping and ip configuration is written only in `service` YAML not in `deployment` `YAML`. service yaml just mapped the deployment yaml using the app name.

Answer (score 0):

The `deployment` object **can**, and often, [should have network properties to expose the applications within the pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster).

Pods are networking cappable objects, with [virtual ethernet interfaces](https://sookocheff.com/post/kubernetes/understanding-kubernetes-networking-model/#pod-to-pod), needed to receive incoming traffic.

On the other hand, `services` are completely network oriented objects, meant mostly to relay network traffic into the pods.

You can think of that as pods (grouped in deployments) as backend and services as load balancers. At the end, both need network capabilities.

In your scenario, I'm not sure how are you exposing your deployment via `load balancer` since its pods doesn't seem to have any open ports.

Since the services exposing your pods are targeting port 9000, you can add it to the pod template in your deployment:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/fitme-xxxxxxx
    name: fitme-sha256
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9000
```

Be sure that it matches the port where your container is actually receiving the incoming requests.